# Maven dependency for GeneratedMockFactory

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

what should be the correct maven dependencies to declare if i want to use org.scalamock.generated.GeneratedMockFactory?

I have a scala project which depends on scalatest_2.10 version 2.0.M5B and scalamock-scalatest version 3.0.1 and it looks like the org.scalamock.generated is in neither of them.

kind regards
 marco

Answer (score 3):

`org.scalamock.generated.GeneratedMockFactory` is a trait that is generated by the [Scalamock compiler plugin](https://github.com/paulbutcher/scalamock-sbt-plugin) for Scalamock 2 (for Scala 2.9 or older). In scalamock 3 (for Scala 2.10/2.11), the use of the compiler plugin is replaced by macros, so that Scalamock now supports the following two types of mocks :

- Macro mocks, using [org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/master/frameworks/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalamock/scalatest/MockFactory.scala)
- Proxy mocks, using [org.scalamock.scalatest.proxy.MockFactory](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/master/frameworks/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalamock/scalatest/proxy/MockFactory.scala)

Please note that macro mocks may fail (at compilation) when trying to mock some complex traits, but they are fully type-checked and have nicer syntax - so it's a good idea to use macro mocks as much as possible, and fall back to proxy mocks when they don't work, [according to Scalamock's author](http://paulbutcher.com/2014/04/15/scalamock-status-report/). He also has a nice step-by-step guide to using Scalamock 3 (with macro mocks) [here](http://paulbutcher.com/2012/10/14/scalamock3-step-by-step/).